Reading lots of files inside do loop in fortran 95
I searched several available answers but could not find the exact solution to my problem.
I have created several .dat files using fortran (95), which are named as '1.dat', '2.dat', '3.dat', ... etc. using the code given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78641612/23104418.
But now I'm trying to write a separate code that 'reads' all those files. I wrote the following code, which is almost same as the previous one as I tried to be clever.
integer :: i, j, ios
character(len=10) :: filename
    
do i = 1, 10
     read(filename, '(I0)') i
     
     filename = trim(adjustl(filename))//'.dat'
     
     open(i, file=filename, status='old', iostat=ios)
      
      if (ios/=0) then
       print*, 'Error opening file ', filename
      
      else
      
      do j = 1, 10
       read(i,*) aa(i,j)         ! This `aa(i,j)` are to save the values somewhere else.
      end do
      
       close(i)
      
      end if
    
    
    end do

But upon compiling, I'm getting the error: Error: Variable ‘i’ at (1) cannot be redefined inside loop beginning at (2)".
(1) means the line read(filename, '(I0)') i;
(2) means the line do i = 1, 10.
I don't know of any more potential error(s) since the code has stopped compiling after this line.
I thought that the same way the previous code assigned names to new files before creating them, this code will assign names to files, that required opening, before reading them.
I need the correction. Thanks!

Just do not use the loop control variable directly both as the unit number and as the file name number at the same time. That is quite insane. Have different variables for different things. Do not use low numbers like 1,2,5 or 6 for unit numbers, that is asking for trouble. Best, use newunit= instead of unit= in open (but with a separate variable!).

I just found your comment "I tried to utilise the same code in this answer to 'read' all the data files created. I tried by changing "write(filename, '(I0)') i", to "read(filename, '(I0)') i".". A doctor would say: If it hurts when you do this, don't do that!

Read reads from the file given into the variable in the input list.
 read(filename, '(I0)') i

reads from the string filename some integer and stores it into variable i. That is not what you wanted.
We have many examples how to do your task at Convert integers to strings to create output filenames at run time

Right, it took me some time to figure out. But I did as follows: " write(filename, '(I0)') i\
filename = trim(adjustl(filename))//'.dat'\
open(i, file=filename, status='old', iostat=ios) "So essentially I just changed the 'status' from 'new' to 'old'. And everything is going on as wanted.

@QuestionTheAnswer I strongly(!) recommend to not use i as the unit number. You are asking for real trouble. You can even use some fixed number like 100. Or do it properly and use newunit=iunit where iunit is an integer variable.
